# Avoid Remote Server call in recyclerview when returning back to an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, picasso, back-stack

I have a recyclerview with images in Activity A, clicking on a button takes me to Activity B in which i have `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` so clicking on the UP button in toolbar goes back to Activity A but i do not want the recyclerview images to be fetched again from server only in this case (while returning from Activity B) in other cases i want it to load from remote server. I'm Using Picasso for loading the images.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(disposalType.getImage()).into(holder.thumbnail1);
```

Comment: Can you please post how/where you are loading your images.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Picasso have memory cache enabled by default. So after returning back it will try to fetch images from memory cache. Or you can specify your own cache policy.

Comment: so if i leave the activity go to another activity and come back, it will use the one in memory cache instead of remote? how to check this or debug and see if its using the memory cache or remote?

Comment: if you leave activity and come back it will not trigger oncreate method, so you can put your recycler view stuff there. But even if it will cause refreshing your list all images will be downloaded from MemoryCache.

Comment: okay  and this memory cache stays until i close the app ?what if image changes in server how to deal with it?

Comment: @SiddarthG Yes, or until cache capacity is oversized, then oldest images will be removed